# zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull not working in jdbc url using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, mariadb

Through an extern properties file url is specified as the following
jdbc:mariadb://xxxxx:3306/xxxxx?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull

The connection works fine and am able to query the DB.
Through hibernate I made an entity that is mapped to a table with a date column. When no date was specified a zero date was inserted by default (0000-00-00).
When I get the date out of an entity with a zero date it gives a date that shows as 00002-10-02 cause java date cant handle a year or month/day that is zero.

The zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull is supposed to handle this and give back null value so i can properly handle these situations and not erroneously give back a completely wrong date.

Ive read through about 50 forum topics but was not able to find a solution.
Let me know if I can provide more information. Thanks.

Comment: Hi I can see you are new here, please update the question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This would suggest you are using a different connection and connection string when using Hibernate.

Answer (score 5):

Try using zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL, that works for me.

I also found this from the docs:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

```
zeroDateTimeBehavior

What should happen when the driver encounters DATETIME values that are composed entirely of zeros (used by MySQL to represent invalid dates)? 
Valid values are "EXCEPTION", "ROUND" and "CONVERT_TO_NULL".

Default: EXCEPTION

Since version: 3.1.4
```

Comment: Worked for me. Despite many resources pointed towards using ```zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull```