# How can we read invalid date column in spark scala from mysql server using jdbc driver url (connection)

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, aws-glue, mysql-connector

I am getting error while reading this column from mysql server

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0000-00-00 |
| 2 | 0000-00-01 |

in the above data set we can handle 0000-00-00 by using mysql server Additional parameter
zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull

but i don't know how to handle this type of date 0000-00-01

help me error message i got

```
Exception in User Class: org.apache.spark.SparkException : Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 6.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 6.0 (TID 11) (10.100.4.111 executor 1): java.sql.SQLException: YEAR
```

i am using this

```
val a = "jdbc:mysql://<host_name>:3306/<database_name>?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"

val mysqlServerDF = sparkSession.read.format("jdbc")
                .option("url", a)
                .option("query", sql)
                .option("user",jdbcUserName)
                .option("password", jdbcPassword)
                .load()
```

sql is a sql query example "select * from table"

Comment: Could you try with "CONVERT_TO_NULL" intead of "convertToNull"?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61407572/2026277

Comment: I tested both "CONVERT_TO_NULL" ,"convertToNull" but same error

Answer (score 0):

If fixing such dates in your database is not an option, I think your best bet would be to handle it directly in your `sql` query. E.g. we can compare for valid date range, which is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31' according to [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html):

```
val sql = """
  select 
    id, 
    case 
      when 
        not cast(date as char(10)) 
        between '1000-01-02' and '9999-12-30' 
      then 
        null 
      else 
        date 
    end 
  from table1"""

val mysqlServerDF = sparkSession.read.format("jdbc")
                .option("url", a)
                .option("query", sql)
                .option("user",jdbcUserName)
                .option("password", jdbcPassword)
                .load()
```